# Fullcalendar.io - businessHours-per-resource not show

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

i use fullcalendar and i need show different business hours (open time) for resource. My actual solution is this:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaDay',
  locale: 'cs',
  slotDuration: '00:15:00',
  scrollTime: scrollTime,
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
  slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
  editable: true,
  droppable: true,
  selectable: true,
  eventLimit: true,
  businessHours: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'
  },
  views: {
    agendaTwoDay: {
      type: 'agenda',
      duration: { days: 2 },
      groupByResource: false,
    }
  },
  resources: [
    {
     id:4,
     title: "Employee 1",
     businessHours: { dow: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
       start:"08:00:00", end:"12:00:00"
     }
    },
    {
     id:5,
     title: "Employee 2"
    }
  ],
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.nette.ajax({
      url: 'data',
      dataType: 'xml',
      data: {
        start: start.unix(),
        end: end.unix()
      },
      success: function(doc) {
        var events = [];

        $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
          events.push({
            id: $(this).attr('id'),
            resourceId: $(this).attr('resourceId'),
            title: $(this).attr('example'),
            description: $(this).attr('description'),
            start: $(this).attr('start'),
            end: $(this).attr('end'),
            color: $(this).attr('color'),
            className: 'formModal',
          });
        });
        callback(events);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

But in calendar i dont see busines time. If I look to source code, I see element  but with height: 0px;

Can you tell me where is problem? And how i can set different working hours on different days in week for one resources?

Thank you,

Comment: It's ok, i updated version of fullcalendar.

Comment: in that case please delete your question